# Lightning Web Component (Lightning-Layout) not available as Custom Layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-layouts

I've been working on a custom layout for a standalone Lightning App Page.  I've successfully deployed the code to an org.  The Layout shows in the Lightning Components in the Setup Menu and shows as an option to ADD to a lightning_HomePage or lightning_AppPage (once a standard layout is selected).

I'm at a loss for what needs to be done to make it available to use as a custom layout to which I could add other components?

Meta File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Lightning Page Templates only work with Aura at this time.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_templates.htm&type=5

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.